# Can I use a program to check the gpio port's value that changed by other program?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have 2 programs, The first one change the value of gpio(I call it changer), the another one will check the gpio port's value(I call it checker), The problem is if I run this 2 program in the same time, can the checker check the value that changed by changer? Thx!

Comment: Any reason not to just try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine. As long as your "checker" does not touch the state of the pins, it is fine to check the value of a pin from multiple processes. Make sure that your checker does not change the pin state, or you'll see very strange behavior.